How can I convert geometry node output to mesh/objects or export geometry node output in a .fbx file?

I'm trying to export this donut setup as a fbx but geometry node changes don't export and if i try to apply the modifier it just does nothing. I found another person asking the same question but there was no answer Blender: Combining geometry nodes with a mesh to export as a single piece object

This video gave me the solution although there was no texture on the sprinkles. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrXZNG4yAa8&ab_channel=ALLTHEWORKS
